# find xpath of parent's sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this input xml.This is my current xpath    `root/Message/Item/IPList/ItemPac`.  from this xpath I want to select value of `<HndlAttrAct></HndlAttrAct>` this tag. what would be xpath relative to current xpath.

```
<root>
<Message>
<Item>
    <IPList>
        <ItemPac>
          <PkgUOM>Unit</PkgUOM>
        </ItemPac>
      </IPList>
      <ItemTms>
        <ItemValue>.01</ItemValue>
      </ItemTms>
      <ItemW>
        <HndlAttrAct>HAA</HndlAttrAct>
        <UnitsPerPickAct></UnitsPerPickAct>
      </ItemW>
    </Item>
  </Message>
</root>
```

Note - I am using xslt 1.0 processor.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `parent::*`, you can traverse to the parent element and work your way back:

```
root/Message/Item/IPList/ItemPac/parent::*/parent::*/ItemW/HndlAttrAct/text()
```

To get only the element and not the value, just remove `text()`:

```
root/Message/Item/IPList/ItemPac/parent::*/parent::*/ItemW/HndlAttrAct``
```

Answer (score 1):

From the context of `ItemPac`, you can get the value of `HndlAttrAct` in the same `Item` using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../ItemW/HndlAttrAct"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Item/ItemW/HndlAttrAct"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another options regarding your sample XML :

```
<xsl:value-of select="../following-sibling::ItemW/HndlAttrAct"/>
```

Select the parent of the current node, then the child of the sibling `ItemW`.

```
<xsl:value-of select="following::ItemW/HndlAttrAct"/>
```

Select the child of the first following `ItemW`.

```
<xsl:value-of select="following::HndlAttrAct"/>
```

Even shorter, select the following `HndlAttract` node.

Comment: Shorter, but more expensive.